# Search is showing inconsistence results when the search result include both html Pages & PDFs

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, pdf

I have the following:-

1. Enterprise wiki site collection inside SP server 2013.
2. inside the "Pages" library we have html wiki pages and pdfs files.

now when i search for a word like "webroot secureanywhere", i will get only the wiki pages (without pdf files) as follow:-

[image]

now if i click on "Pdf" under the "Result Type" i will get the pdf , as follow:-

[image]

but the problem is when i click on "All" under the "Result Type", then only the Wiki pages will appear, although the logic says that when i click on "ALL" then both the pdfs and the wiki pages should appear is this correct ? so why "ALL" will be translated as show "All Wiki pages only" and not "show all items such as wiki pages , pdfs, ms word , etc.."

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like trim duplicates hits you.

1. go grab the searchquerytool https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/
2. add your hostname in the connection pane and the site where your wiki is placed
3. search for "webroot secureanywhere"
4. toggle trimduplicates to false.

If you have 2 results then - buy me a beer :) and use this script http://blogs.technet.com/b/searchguys/archive/2013/04/04/sp2013-getting-at-the-search-results-web-part-search-criteria-via-powershell.aspx to enable duplicates if you still want them.